# Trouble converting column names to dates in R

Tags: r, date

I have a subset of columns that I want to change to date.  Here's the basic working code:

```
#Data comes in this format:
January_2019= c(4, 5)
February_2019= c(1,2)
OtherVariable = c(3,5)
 
df <- data.frame(January_2019, February_2019, OtherVariable)

#Replace underscore with blank
names(df) <- gsub("_", " ", names(df))

#Select date columns   
dateColumns <- c("January 2019",
                 "February 2019")

#Change these date columns to date
names(df[dateColumns]) <- as.Date(names(df[dateColumns]), format = '%B %Y')
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, the column names don't change to dates.  Can anyone point me in right direction here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need a day also in the `Date` format.  Can `paste` a dummy `01` and change the `format` to `%d %B %Y`.  Also, as `Date` is internally a `integer`, convert it to `character` before assigning to the column names to prevent the coercion to `integer`

```
i1 <- match(dateColumns, names(df))
names(df)[i1] <- as.character(as.Date(paste0('01 ',
         names(df)[i1]), format = '%d %B %Y'))

names(df)
#[1] "2019-01-01"    "2019-02-01"    "OtherVariable"
```

---

If the intention is to reorder the columns and only for those 'Date' columns, order the columns and the column names with the same `order` on the subset of columns

```
i2 <- order(as.Date(paste0('01 ',
         names(df)[i1]), format = '%d %B %Y'))
df[i1] <- df[i1[i2]]
names(df)[i1] <- names(df)[i1[i2]]
```

---

In the OP's example, the date columns are in `order` already.  Suppose, we have another dataset which are arranged differently

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame("January 2017" = 1:3, "otherColumn2" = 1,
       "December 2009" = 4:6,
      "August 2016" = 7:9, "September 2003" = 10:12, 
 "January 2007" = 7:9, "otherColumn1" = rnorm(3), check.names = FALSE)
df2 <- data.table::copy(df1)

dateColumns <- grep('\\w+ \\d{4}$', names(df1), value = TRUE)
i1 <- match(dateColumns, names(df1))
i2 <- order(as.Date(paste0('01 ',
         names(df1)[i1]), format = '%d %B %Y'))
df2[i1] <- df2[i1[i2]]
names(df2)[i1] <- names(df2)[i1[i2]]
```

Now, we check the original data 'df1'

```
df1
#  January 2017 otherColumn2 December 2009 August 2016 September 2003 January 2007 otherColumn1
#1            1            1             4           7             10            7   -0.5458808
#2            2            1             5           8             11            8    0.5365853
#3            3            1             6           9             12            9    0.4196231
```

and the sorted columns with 'df2' (leaving the other columns in the same spot)

```
df2
#   September 2003 otherColumn2 January 2007 December 2009 August 2016 January 2017 otherColumn1
#1             10            1            7             4           7            1   -0.5458808
#2             11            1            8             5           8            2    0.5365853
#3             12            1            9             6           9            3    0.4196231
```

---

Or another option is `as.yearmon` from `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
names(df)[i1] <- as.character(as.Date(as.yearmon(names(df)[i1]), '%B %Y')))
```

Comment: Akrun, Thanks!  I think this will work.  One more question.  Once the column names are in date format (all I really need is month-year), I want to sort the columns to go from oldest to newest.  Is it possible to sort the order of the columns this way?

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 I added a better example to show how the code works.